# Parsing dynamically generated urls from aspx page

Tags: python, asp.net, python-3.x, parsing

I'm trying to parse an aspx page containing a table, 
each row has an element that opens a pdf file on a new tab.

The url that the element opens is stored inside a script in a form in the page source, but the script seems to be generated for each file only after you actually click on the element.

My end goal is to save all those pdf files, I thought the best solution would be saving the urls and using requests to save the contents of each url.
But I couldn't find a way to get all the urls without actually clicking each element.

The HTML of the script after clicking an element:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
    var docUrl=escape('/NGCS.Web.Secured/Viewer/NGCSViewerPage.aspx?DocumentNumber=4105ea67709148d7984ce9a2efc48157');
    window.open(unescape(docUrl)); </script>
```

The wanted value from this example is either the string listed in 'docUrl', which is:'/NGCS.Web.Secured/Viewer/NGCSViewerPage.aspx?DocumentNumber=4105ea67709148d7984ce9a2efc48157', or the 'DocumentNumber' from within the string, which is:'4105ea67709148d7984ce9a2efc48157'.

Either one of those values can be used to navigate to the dynamic url of the page containing the wanted file.

Couldn't find something similar to my question.

Comment: Can you provide expected value?

Comment: Expected value is written at the end, either the full string listed in 'docURL' which in the example given supposed to be:'/NGCS.Web.Secured/Viewer/NGCSViewerPage.aspx?DocumentNumber=4105ea67709148d7984ce9a2efc48157', or the 'DocumentNumber' alone from the string, which is:'4105ea67709148d7984ce9a2efc48157'.  I've edited the question to be more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much information on HOW are are holding this object so I'm going to assume its a string.
you can use a regex to grab the document number, like so:

```
import re
s = ''' <script language="JavaScript">
    var docUrl=escape('/NGCS.Web.Secured/Viewer/NGCSViewerPage.aspx?DocumentNumber=4105ea67709148d7984ce9a2efc48157');
    window.open(unescape(docUrl)); </script>'''
print(re.search('DocumentNumber=([\w]+)',s).groups())
```